# ReactJS - How to get access to state value inside a funciton?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have reactjs component:

```js
import React, { Component, actions } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";


class CardTradeSim extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ObtenerdataETH: [],
      ObtenerdataBTC: [],
      ObtenerdataXRP: [],
    };

  }

  render() {

    function DevuelveValorCrypto(testing) {
      console.log("check received: ", testing)
      const TipoCrypto = testing;

      let test123 = this.state.ObtenerdataETH.price
      console.log("check received: valor de test123", test123)

      return (
        <DIV>bla bla </DIV>
      );
    }
    ...
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    token: state.token,
    //selectvalue: state.value

  };
};

//Dispaching to STORE:
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSelectCrypto: (value) => dispatch(actions.SelectCrypto(value))
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CardTradeSim);
```

I receives some properties of `this.state` like this: `this.state.ObtenerdataETH` and is working perfecty.

But When I needed inside a fucntion I have this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

How to use it inside a function?

Comment: use an arrow function. Rewrite `function DevuelveValorCrypto(testing) {` to `DevuelveValorCrypto = (testing) => {`

Comment: @Neil arrow functions cannot use this must be a function.

Comment: why arrow function will not work?

Comment: where are you calling `DevuelveValorCrypto`? Your usage is not clear

Comment: that's right, but also not an impossible thing.. however it's not an error :)

Comment: I am calling DevuelveValorCrypto() inside render. 
I have not mentioned it to simplify the code.

Comment: why don't you make it as a method?

Comment: i assume you pass the function as a prop to another component in render function? when you pass, write it like this - someprop={`DevuelveValorCrypto.bind(this)`}

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by Neil, you have to use arrow functions instead of named because arrow function doesn't have a scope:

```js
import React, { Component, actions } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class CardTradeSim extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ObtenerdataETH: [],
      ObtenerdataBTC: [],
      ObtenerdataXRP: [],
    };
  }

  // Arrow function
  DevuelveValorCrypto = (testing) => {
    console.log("check received: ", testing);
    const TipoCrypto = testing;

    let test123 = this.state.ObtenerdataETH.price;
    console.log("check received: valor de test123", test123);

    return <DIV>bla bla </DIV>;
  };

  render() {
    <DevuelveValorCrypto testing="..." />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    token: state.token,
    //selectvalue: state.value
  };
};

//Dispaching to STORE:
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSelectCrypto: (value) => dispatch(actions.SelectCrypto(value)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CardTradeSim);
```

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend using Functional programming.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const CardTradeSim = (props) => {

    const [ObtenerdataETH, setObtenerdataETH] = useState([]);
    const [ObtenerdataBTC, setObtenerdataBTC] = useState([]);
    const [ObtenerdataXRP, setObtenerdataXRP] = useState([]);

    const DevuelveValorCrypto = testing => {
        console.log("check received: ", testing)
        const TipoCrypto = testing;
        let test123 = ObtenerdataETH.price
        console.log("check received: valor de test123", test123)
    }

    return <DIV> bla bla {DevuelveValorCrypto({})} </DIV>

};
```

Comment: How do you call a functional programming from  inside render() ?

Comment: render() is used for class components. functional components don't need render they use return. this way you can be in touch with your states without using "this" scope